# SliverAppBar and Tab bar overlap while scrolling in NestedScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

SliverAppBar and Tab bar overlap when scrolling in NestedScrollView as shown in the following image:

[image: SliverAppBar and Tab bar overlap when scrolling in NestedScrollView]

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the body widget or `tabBarView` with `SingleChildScrollView()`

```
   SingleChildScrollView(
child: theBodyWidgetWhereItOverflows()
)
```

Comment: not working properly

Answer (score 0):

wrap your widget in flexibleSpace with FlexibleSpaceBar()